# Invalid JSON Data From requests.get

Tags: python, json

I am querying a whole-house power monitor (Neurio) that returns data in JSON format.

When I enter the URL in a Chrome browser, http://192.168.1.87/current-sample,  I get properly formatted JSON data as follows:

`{"sensorId":"0x0000C47F51019B7D","timestamp":"2016-12-24T14:56:08Z","channels":[{"type":"PHASE_A_CONSUMPTION","ch":1,"eImp_Ws":55552784178,"eExp_Ws":23,"p_W":3188,"q_VAR":321,"v_V":121.753},{"type":"PHASE_B_CONSUMPTION","ch":2,"eImp_Ws":62493402411,"eExp_Ws":23,"p_W":3499,"q_VAR":263,"v_V":120.334},{"type":"CONSUMPTION","ch":3,"eImp_Ws":118046186640,"eExp_Ws":41,"p_W":6687,"q_VAR":584,"v_V":121.044}],"cts":[{"ct":1,"p_W":3188,"q_VAR":321,"v_V":121.753},{"ct":2,"p_W":3499,"q_VAR":263,"v_V":120.334},{"ct":3,"p_W":0,"q_VAR":0,"v_V":0.000},{"ct":4,"p_W":0,"q_VAR":0,"v_V":121.747}]}`

which parses correctly in JSONLint.

When I attempt to pull the same data in Python using the following line of code:

```
pvdata = requests.get('http://'+neurioip+'/current-sample').json()
```

The returned data includes invalid characters as in the following example. (Data retrieved by simply printing pvdata)

`{u'channels': [{u'eExp_Ws': 23, u'v_V': 122.434, u'ch': 1, u'eImp_Ws': 55554346060, u'q_VAR': 305, u'p_W': 1489, u'type': u'PHASE_A_CONSUMPTION'}, {u'eExp_Ws': 23, u'v_V': 120.981, u'ch': 2, u'eImp_Ws': 62495160471, u'q_VAR': 237, u'p_W': 1872, u'type': u'PHASE_B_CONSUMPTION'}, {u'eExp_Ws': 41, u'v_V': 121.708, u'ch': 3, u'eImp_Ws': 118049506582, u'q_VAR': 542, u'p_W': 3360, u'type': u'CONSUMPTION'}], u'sensorId': u'0x0000C47F51019B7D', u'cts': [{u'p_W': 1489, u'q_VAR': 305, u'v_V': 122.434, u'ct': 1}, {u'p_W': 1872, u'q_VAR': 237, u'v_V': 120.981, u'ct': 2}, {u'p_W': 0, u'q_VAR': 0, u'v_V': 0.0, u'ct': 3}, {u'p_W': 0, u'q_VAR': 0, u'v_V': 122.432, u'ct': 4}], u'timestamp': u'2016-12-24T15:03:42Z'}`

Data retreived using the following code:

`for keys,values in pvdata.items():
    print(keys)
    print(values)`

`channels
[{u'eExp_Ws': 23, u'v_V': 122.843, u'ch': 1, u'eImp_Ws': 55555370977, u'q_VAR': 14, u'p_W': 230, u'type': u'PHASE_A_CONSUMPTION'}, {u'eExp_Ws': 23, u'v_V': 121.088, u'ch': 2, u'eImp_Ws': 62496733790, u'q_VAR': -3, u'p_W': 661, u'type': u'PHASE_B_CONSUMPTION'}, {u'eExp_Ws': 41, u'v_V': 121.965, u'ch': 3, u'eImp_Ws': 118052104817, u'q_VAR': 12, u'p_W': 890, u'type': u'CONSUMPTION'}]
sensorId
0x0000C47F51019B7D
cts
[{u'p_W': 230, u'q_VAR': 14, u'v_V': 122.843, u'ct': 1}, {u'p_W': 661, u'q_VAR': -3, u'v_V': 121.088, u'ct': 2}, {u'p_W': 0, u'q_VAR': 0, u'v_V': 0.0, u'ct': 3}, {u'p_W': 0, u'q_VAR': 0, u'v_V': 122.84, u'ct': 4}]
timestamp
2016-12-24T15:25:16Z`

The "u" characters makes this unparsable in JSONlint or in subsequent lines of code in my program.

I've looked at default character encoding in my Python environment but that doesn't seem to lead anywhere. I'm looking for other ideas to investigate.

Comment: As an aside, python 3 has been out a long time. Move to it if you can.

Comment: If you want the raw JSON string, don't call `json()` on the response. Instead, just read the `.content` attribute. The `json()` method returns a Python `dict`.

Comment: Good point about python 3. I'll move this program forward.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on .content. This gives me more options to pursue if I can't get the dictionary to parse correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.json()` is what parses the JSON. It's done. You have a python dictionary which you can use normally now (as you've already seen by iterating through it).

Comment: Yes, I have the dictionary but it includes invalid characters that do not parse as valid JSON in JSONlint and make subsequent attempts to use the dictionary fail with Index Out of Range

Comment: @user4372 it's been parsed, don't try to parse it as JSON again. If using the dictionary is failing that's because of a different error in your code. Ask a new question with your failing code and `pvdata` as a dictionary. There is no JSON problem here.

Comment: @user4372 `pvdata` is a python `dict` not a JSON serialized string. It looks like you just printed the `dict` and then copied it to jsonlint? But that's just the python string representation of a python dict. Also, the `for` loop you show us to print keys and values works just fine... so this is a python dict working properly.

Comment: Ok, I have a valid dictionary but with invalid characters that make my following attempt at looking up the value of a key fail: cons_W = pvdata['channels'][4]['p_W']  The json.dumps does remove the invalid "u"'s but leaves me with a list instead of a dictionary.

Comment: @user4372 `pvdata['channels']` has only 3 elements, so the highest index you can possibly use is 2, not 4. Also stop worrying about the `u`s, it's just Python telling you it's a unicode object, it's harmless.

Comment: OK, that's an explanation for the "u"s and I think you've pointed me in the right direction. I'll call this one solved and go back to work on the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is unparsable since the string representation of a dict simply isn't JSON; you need to remarshall the dict to JSON if that's what you need:

```
In [36]: d = {u'channels': [{u'eExp_Ws': 23, u'v_V': 122.434, u'ch': 1, u'eImp_Ws': 55554346060, u'q_VAR': 305, u'p_W': 1489, u'type': u'PHASE_A_CONSUMPTION'}, {u'eExp_Ws': 23, u'v_V': 120.981, u'ch': 2, u'eImp_Ws': 62495160471, u'q_VAR': 237, u'p_W': 1872, u'type': u'PHASE_B_CONSUMPTION'}, {u'eExp_Ws': 41, u'v_V': 121.708, u'ch': 3, u'eImp_Ws': 118049506582, u'q_VAR': 542, u'p_W': 3360, u'type': u'CONSUMPTION'}], u'sensorId': u'0x0000C47F51019B7D', u'cts': [{u'p_W': 1489, u'q_VAR': 305, u'v_V': 122.434, u'ct': 1}, {u'p_W': 1872, u'q_VAR': 237, u'v_V': 120.981, u'ct': 2}, {u'p_W': 0, u'q_VAR': 0, u'v_V': 0.0, u'ct': 3}, {u'p_W': 0, u'q_VAR': 0, u'v_V': 122.432, u'ct': 4}], u'timestamp': u'2016-12-24T15:03:42Z'}

In [38]: json.dumps(d)
Out[38]: '{"sensorId": "0x0000C47F51019B7D", "timestamp": "2016-12-24T15:03:42Z", "cts": [{"q_VAR": 305, "ct": 1, "v_V": 122.434, "p_W": 1489}, {"q_VAR": 237, "ct": 2, "v_V": 120.981, "p_W": 1872}, {"q_VAR": 0, "ct": 3, "v_V": 0.0, "p_W": 0}, {"q_VAR": 0, "ct": 4, "v_V": 122.432, "p_W": 0}], "channels": [{"q_VAR": 305, "type": "PHASE_A_CONSUMPTION", "p_W": 1489, "v_V": 122.434, "ch": 1, "eImp_Ws": 55554346060, "eExp_Ws": 23}, {"q_VAR": 237, "type": "PHASE_B_CONSUMPTION", "p_W":
1872, "v_V": 120.981, "ch": 2, "eImp_Ws": 62495160471, "eExp_Ws": 23}, {"q_VAR": 542, "type": "CONSUMPTION", "p_W": 3360, "v_V": 121.708, "ch": 3, "eImp_Ws": 118049506582, "eExp_Ws": 41}]}'
```